# Парсинг переменной list в файле и замена его в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, io

Есть .py файл и в нем переменная. Надо перезаписать эту переменную именно в файле. Надо считать list INSTALLED_APPS, добавить еще один параметр и перезаписать файл. Как лучше это сделать? Думал о модуле parsingconfig, но кажется это какой-то костыль будет

**test.py**

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'test',
    'test2',
]
```

Comment: Какова цель этой операции? вы создаете какой-то глобальный файл конфигурации? тогда храните переменные в json, читайте и перезаписывайте файл целиком.

Comment: это файл в setting.py в django